# Как сократить одно или два полных ФИО в SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Запрос разбивает одним (первым) полным ФИО. В ячейке t_name указано полное ФИО (фамилия, имя и отчество)

Запрос:

```
SELECT data, para, idgroup, subj_name,
    SUBSTR(t_name, 1, INSTR(t_name, ' ')-1) as f_name,
    SUBSTR(t_name, INSTR(t_name, ' ')+1,1) as l_name,
    SUBSTR(t_name, INSTR(SUBSTR(t_name, INSTR(t_name, ' ')+1), ' ')+ INSTR(t_name, ' ')+1,1) as o_name,
    t_aud
FROM subs
```

К примеру в одной строке (ячейки) будет находится 2 (два) полных ФИО.

**Можно ли построить один запрос так чтобы она сокращала одно или два ФИО?**

ФИО:

```
Жуковский Иван Петрович
Сидоров Николай Петрович, Петрова Марина Николаевна
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
Жуковский И.П.
Сидоров Н.П., Петрова М.Н.
```

Comment: Вам нужен модуль [regex-replace](https://github.com/gwenn/sqlite-regex-replace-ext)